# How to create an empty list in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the following XSD type definition

```
<complexType name="a">
    <sequence>
       <element name=”a1” default=”0 1 2 3”>
          <simpleType>
             <list itemType=”nonNegativeInteger"/>
        </simpleType>
    </element>
```

In the XML, I want to differentiate between the empty list case and the null case:
I would expect that for:

```
<a1>   </a1>
```

the parser will return the string “   “, which represents the empty list.

While for

```
<a1/>
```

the parser will return the default value.

However, in both cases the parser returns the default value. I am using c++ xerces 2_8

Answer (score 2):

The xml:space attribute can be placed on any elements in the XML document and given a value of preserve to signal that the white space is significant. (xml:space="preserve")

Comment: I tried it out. But still, the xerces parser returns for this element the default value, instead of the whitespace string.